# How I can run a script at the beginning of React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I think it's a simple question but I'm not clear on the best way to do it.

In addition to run my React App, I need asynchronously and independently to run a script to (for example) add user fingerprint to my database.

The result of this script does not influence the application but I need to include this script inside App because I'm using App functions.

I can think of two ways to do it:

1) Inside `index.js`

```
import { add_fingerprint }  from './utils/Functions';
add_fingerprint();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

2) Inside `App` component:

```
import { add_fingerprint }  from './utils/Functions';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    add_fingerprint();
  }

  render () {
    return (<div>My app</div>)
  }

}
```

`add_fingerprint` function:

```
export function add_fingerprint () {

  import axios from 'axios';
  import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

  setTimeout(function () {
    Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
    //axios call to add to my database         
    })  
  }, 500)

}
```

What is the most correct way?

Comment: Possibly none of them, because add_fingerprint doesn't expose a promise that could be chained. It's unclear whether the app depends on the result of `add_fingerprint` call.

Comment: I've update my question. The app does not depends of `add_fingerprint` results

Comment: Then both options are acceptable. *I need to include this script inside App because I'm using App functions* - I suppose you meant 'app' (application) and not 'App' (root component), didn't you?

Comment: correct, I mean to application not to the component

Answer (score 0):

Second point is correct.

If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount